# Optional sysproperty in macrodef for java jar

Tags: java, ant

There is a project I try yo compile : https://github.com/real-logic/simple-binary-encoding
However, when I try to compile using ant with targets for cpp98, compilation fails. After much analysis, it fails because some macro in build.xml tries to have optional sysproperty when launching a jar, but fails to do so.

Here is a working build.xml made as an extract of what makes the project fail (it needs several files to launch, however):

```ant
<project name="optional-sysproperty" default="test" basedir="." xmlns:unless="ant:unless">
    <macrodef name="sbetool">
        <attribute name="outputdir" default=""/>
        <attribute name="targetlanguage" default=""/>
        <attribute name="targetnamespace" default=""/>
        <attribute name="generatestubs" default=""/>
        <attribute name="generateir" default=""/>
        <attribute name="validationxsd" default=""/>
        <attribute name="stoponerror" default=""/>
        <element name="schemafiles" implicit="yes" />
        <sequential>
            <java jar="sbe.jar" failonerror="true" fork="true">
                <sysproperty key="sbe.output.dir" value="@{outputdir}"/>
                <sysproperty key="sbe.target.language" value="@{targetlanguage}" unless:blank="@{targetlanguage}"/>
                <sysproperty key="sbe.target.namespace" value="@{targetnamespace}" unless:blank="@{targetnamespace}"/>
                <sysproperty key="sbe.generate.stubs" value="@{generatestubs}" unless:blank="@{generatestubs}"/>
                <sysproperty key="sbe.generate.ir" value="@{generateir}" unless:blank="@{generateir}"/>
                <sysproperty key="sbe.validation.xsd" value="@{validationxsd}" unless:blank="@{validationxsd}"/>
                <sysproperty key="sbe.validation.stop.on.error" value="@{stoponerror}" unless:blank="@{stoponerror}"/>
                <schemafiles/>
            </java>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="test"
            description="Generate serialized IR stubs for Java">
        <sbetool outputdir="${basedir}" targetlanguage="Java"
            validationxsd="SimpleBinary1-0.xsd">
            <arg value="sbe-test.xml"/>
        </sbetool>
    </target>
</project>
```

When launching using `ant -v`, I get the following:

```
test:
     [java] Executing '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java' with arguments:
     [java] '-Dsbe.output.dir=/home/adrien'
     [java] '-Dsbe.target.language=Java'
     [java] '-Dsbe.target.namespace='
     [java] '-Dsbe.generate.stubs='
     [java] '-Dsbe.generate.ir='
     [java] '-Dsbe.validation.xsd=SimpleBinary1-0.xsd'
     [java] '-Dsbe.validation.stop.on.error='
     [java] '-jar'
     [java] '/home/adrien/sbe.jar'
     [java] 'sbe-test.xml'
     [java]
     [java] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [java] not part of the command.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

The sysproperties have been used with empty values, which is not the goal of this macrodef. While on this target the build is successful, the jar failed to create necessary files due to these empty sysproperties. From this project documentation ( https://github.com/real-logic/simple-binary-encoding/wiki/Sbe-Tool-Guide ), some of these properties should not be used, in particular :

```
sbe.target.namespace: Namespace to be used for generated code. Equates package for Java. If not provided then the package attribute from the schema will be used.
```

To sum up, my question is **Is there a way to make these sysproperties actually optional in this macro ?** This is not my project and I do not know anything about ant, so I would be grateful if you could help me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that `<schemafiles/>`? That's defined by `<element.../>` and not an `<attribute.../>` in your Macro definition. There's no reason why your system properties could not also be defined the same way.

Of course, you will have to change the call to your Macro too. This means that if someone wants to set system properties, they'd have to put those `<sysproperties/>` lines in their Macro call if they want them set. Imagine the macro is defined as:

```
<macrodef name="sbetool">
    <element name="sysproperties"/>
    <element name="schemafiles"/>    <!-- Note "implicit" has been removed-->
```

If I want those system properties, I'd have to do it in my call:

```
<sbetool>
    <sysproperties>
         <sysproperty key="sbe.output.dir" value="..."/>
         <sysproperty key="sbe.target.language" value="..."/> 
         <sysproperty key="sbe.target.namespace" value="..."/>
    <sysproperties/>
     <schemafiles>
         <arg value="sbe-test.xml"/>
     <schemafiles/>
</sbetool>
```

If something must be set to some sort of value, make it an `<attribute.../>` with a default value. If something is optional, make it an `<element.../>`. For example, you might want `outputdir`. `targetlanguage`, and maybe even `validationxsd` be attributes while everything else is an element. Then if `targetlanguage` isn't set, make the default `java`, and test to see if `outputdir` and `validationxml` are set, and if not, fail:

```
<fail message="Must set &quot;outputdir&quot; and &quot;validationxsd&quot.">
    <condition>
        <or>
            <equals arg1="@{outputdir}" arg2=""/>
            <equals arg1="@{validationxml}" arg2=""/>
        </or>
    </condition>
</fail>
```